# How to fix page not updating cell info with innerHTML on async function

Tags: javascript, web3js

This is the sample code given on the blockgeeks, to get it you can:

> git clone https://github.com/blockgeeks/eth102.git

The web page comes out blank and never populates with the columns with the block information. The web console  does show the block objects getting retrieved and the following two messages:

- ReferenceError: web3 is not defined  index.html:29:13
- TypeError: r is not a function  web3.min.js:1:59664

I only have firefox but do not believe this would be an issue.

On the debugger (sources/outline) tab show no error.

Tried using this other line instead as per doc, but same issue:

> let web3 = new Web3(new
>   Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Blockchain Explorer</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<table id="blocks" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Hash</th>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="./web3.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        updateBlocks();
    };
    //console.log(updateBlocks());
    async function updateBlocks() {
        let web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
        let latest = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
        //console.log(web3);

        for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            let block = await web3.eth.getBlock(latest-i);
            printBlock(block);
            //console.log(block);
        }
    }
    //console.log(block);
    function printBlock(block) {
        var table = document.getElementById('blocks');
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = block.number;
        cell2.innerHTML = block.hash;
        cell3.innerHTML = block.timestamp;
        //console.log(table);
        //console.log(printBlock(block));
    }
          //console.log(printBlock(block));
</script>
```

Comment: figure out where it is failing.... console.log and debugger are your friends here.

Comment: @epascarello I did test but nothing showed, but It is good to add what console.log I tested for everyone to see, let me update question.

Comment: The API coming from `web3.min.js` is the unknown input. We do not know what to expect from class `Web3`? Is `.givenProvider` a property of `Web3`? Why is it needed to instantiate `Web3`? Is `Web3` an extension of a base class? Does `.eth.getBlockNumber();` return a Promise?

Comment: @zer00ne yes getBlocknumber returns promise. givenProvider would be property of eth, if I understood right:  https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#givenprovider

Comment: What is in `console.log(latest)` placed after line:`let latest = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();`?

Comment: @zer00ne it looks like I'm not authorized:  Source map error: request failed with status 403
Resource URL: https://cdn.ethers.io/scripts/ethers-v4.min.js
Source Map URL: ethers.min.js.map[Learn More]

Answer (score 0):

Fix was to run **ganache-cli**

and use:

> let web3 = new Web3(new
>   Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");

instead of

> let web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);